# Compile-time type constraint for run-time type

Tags: c#, .net, types

I want to be able to use the System.Type with a given constraint at compile-time;

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

```
internal abstract class BaseClass {}
internal class SubClass : BaseClass {}
internal class OtherClass {}

internal class Consumer
{
    public void DoSomething(Type pType) {}
    public void DoSomething(BaseClass pBaseClass) {}
    public void DoSomething<tBaseClass>(tBaseClass pBaseClass) where tBaseClass : BaseClass {}
}

[TestFixture()]
public class TypeConstraintTest
{
    [Test()]
    public void TestCase1()
    {
        var lConsumer = new Consumer();

        lConsumer.DoSomething(typeof (SubClass));
        // This should not be allowed. Should have a type constraint.
        lConsumer.DoSomething(typeof (OtherClass));

        lConsumer.DoSomething(null as SubClass);
        // This will generate a compiler error, but it's
        // not an elegant solution, not easily readable/understandable.
        lConsumer.DoSomething(null as OtherClass);
    }
}
```

Hope this other example helps to clarify my intentions (Apologies if it is unclear as I had to write it quickly):

```
[TestFixture()]
public class ExampleTest
{
    internal interface GroupingInterface {}
    internal interface TargetInterface {}
    internal class Class1 : GroupingInterface, TargetInterface {}
    internal class Class2 : GroupingInterface {}

[Test()]
void TestCase()
{
    var lGroup = new List<GroupingInterface>() { new Class1(), new Class2() };

    foreach(var lClass in lGroup)
    {
        this.TestMethod(lClass.GetType());

        // This works, but we are passing the object just for forcing the type.
        // We are not going to use the object itself, so it would be better not
        // To pass the reference to the specific object if there is a way...
        this.TestMethodWithInstance(lClass);

        // Don't know the type at compile-time as it is variable.
        //this.TargetMethodWithGeneric<???>

        // Ideally, there should be something like a generic "variable" method:
        //this.TargetMethodWithGeneric<typeFrom(lClass)>
        // This should give a compiler error as a GroupingInterface is not a TargetInterface.
        // But, if we pass any TargetInterface subtype it should compile.
    }
}

void TestMethod(Type pType)
{
    // At this point, we want to make sure pType is
    // a subtype of TargetInterface at compile-time.

    // SHOULD NOT BE AT RUNTIME, SHOULD NOT COMPILE IF WRONG TYPE PASSED:
    if (pType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof (TargetInterface))) throw new Exception();
}

void TestMethodWithInstance(TargetInterface pClass)
{
    var lSubType = pClass.GetType();

    // Do something with the type...
}

void TargetMethodWithGeneric<tType>() where tType : TargetInterface
{
    // Do something with tType.
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more details on the requirement, your question isn't very clear.

Comment: // This should not be allowed. Should have a type constraint.
lConsumer.DoSomething(typeof (OtherClass));

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way to do what you are asking at compile time. `System.Type` is the type expected and given however, with your generic I would argue that it is exactly the solution you want. Typically you wouldn't pass null in directly to a method anyway, it would be a variable of some type removing the requirement of casting. If what you are trying to do doesn't actually take a parameter but just a type you could change the definition to better match.

```
public void DoSomething<tBaseClass>() where tBaseClass : BaseClass 
{
}
```

Then the caller need only specify the type.

```
lConsumer.DoSomething<OtherClass>();
```

---

### Edit

I am still not understanding the need for something other than what you have. Even if it is a list of some other type, you can just use Linq to filter it to the type you are interested in using `OfType<T>()`.

```
[Test()]
public void TestCase()
{
    var lGroup = new List<GroupingInterface>() { new Class1(), new Class2() };

    // If you know you need to extract classes of a certain type you can use this:
    foreach (var lclass in lGroup.OfType<TargetInterface>())
    {
        // using OfType means lclass is already cast as the type expected, if the object is not of that type it will not be iterated
        TestMethodWithInstance(lclass);
    }        
}
```

Comment: The problem with generics is that I can just specify the type at compile-time (unless I want to use reflection); I would like to be able to pass the type at runtime, but make sure that type is a subtype of a given one. My solution in the code is working, but I don't like the idea of casting a null to a type and passing a useless variable.

Comment: @Uno Then please update the question to reflect that, it currently only mentions wanting to fail at compile time

Comment: @Uno can you add an example of where you wouldn't know the type at compile time but it works with the null cast?

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for the runtime check:

```
if( !typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(t) )
    throw new Exception("Must be BaseClass derivative");
```

Comment: It needs to have this check at compile-time rather than run-time.

Comment: @Uno Using [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) you can make runtime checks in to compile time checks.

Comment: I discovered Code Contracts yesterday, and I think they are just perfect for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you wanting to use generics as opposed to just defining the interface or base class you are passing in? There is no reason to use generics when you want specific types.

Comment: Because passing the object is pointless and wrong when you don't mean to use it. In practical case I should save the object against a DTO with this approach, which will also pass all this information through a web service without any purpose.

Comment: Im sorry, I thought DoSomething was accepting an instance in most of the cases, based on the definitions already. Reading back over I can see your tests are based on not passing it in. Regardless, using the generics syntax seems overkill if you want a specific abstract base or interface, since you could just statically use the type (aka no need to do anything dynamic)